# How to make Macbook Pro recognise gigabit speed of ethernet adapter dongle via USB-C connection?

Tags: network, usb, ethernet

It works with up to 100mbps, and it shows in Network as "USB 10/100LAN", but I know it can do up to 1000mbps, but when trying to add + a new interface, the "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" does not appear as an option. The rest of the dongle works. Ethernet adapter works up to that speed.

How can I make the Mac recognise the full speed of the dongle, namely connect under a "USB 10/100/1000 LAN" connection and actually run full speed?

It says in the box 1000mbps.

[image]

I had another adapter, different model, that stopped working, that did show as "USB 10/100/1000 LAN", and did run close to 1000mbps in tests.

[image]

It reaches 1000mbps in other laptops and the seller has confirmed other clients, presumably using other laptops or OSs, don't have the problem.

It's a non-branded dongle. I have tried installing Realtek drivers but it didn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Make / Model? What does it show in About This Mac - System Information - USB? Are you plugging the Ethernet cable into a Gigabit switch, etc?

Comment: What makes you certain that it can do 1,000mbps?

Comment: Thanks to both. I answered in the body of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Judging from your screenshots it seems like the LAN cable is **not directly** plugged into your Mac, instead:

`LAN cable` → `USB 2.0 Hub`→ `4-port USB 2.1 Hub` → `USB 3.1 MBP Controller`

[USB 2 spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0) does **not** allow for high speed data connection like **1GBit/s**. As mentioned in the system report, the **maximum speed is 480MBit/s**. Therefore you can't establish a 1000MBit/s connection.

As long as you have **one device** in this connection tree that is not at **least** capable of **USB 3.0 speeds**, you will not get the faster 1GBit/s speed on your LAN connection.

---

**Edit**: There is another faster `4-port USB 3.1 Hub` being mentioned in the system report. I think that since your dongle has so many ports, it also has two different controllers that are being recognized by the Mac and shown as separates Hubs, although they are one dongle.

Comment: Nice catch.  That's likely the problem.  It's common for USB 3.x devices to fall back to USB 2.0 speeds when plugged into a USB 2.0 port since it's often preferable to work at 1/2 or 1/10th the speed than not work at all.

Comment: Yes! I had a similar problem where my hard drives would (due to slow USB Hubs) drop from ~200mb/s read/write speeds to as low as 30mb/s. Also the USB 3.x naming is **really** confusing.

Comment: You say "There is another faster 4-port USB 3.1 Hub being mentioned in the system report, connected to a different MBP port." In fact there is only one dongle connected to the port, and nothing else other than the power cable. All ports, I believe are the same in the 2020 macbook pro, which is what I'm using. Nothing else is connected to the dongle. I'm adding a photo of the dongle. So far this doesn't solve the problem. The dongle appears to be 1000mbps capable, yet doesn't work at that speed when connected to a USB 3 capable port.

Comment: I See. System report from the screenshot definitely tells us that there is some USB 2.0 connection limiting the speeds. Please edit your question and add those details, maybe a link to the dongle would be helpful too. Depending on your Mac model the ports are **not** the same : https://www.forbes.com/sites/johnkoetsier/2020/06/03/the-unforgivable-sin-apple-committed-with-the-2020-macbook-pro/

Comment: Now after thinking about the second mentioned USB 3.1 port: this is most likely the same dongle but it needs two USB controllers for all the different connections it offers, which then show up as two separate devices. Interesting though that the LAN port (at least on macOS) shows up as connected to the USB 2 controller/Hub. How did you verify that speed is 1GBit/s on other hardware? Did you use something like https://www.speedtest.net or just rely on system information?

Comment: Sorry for another comment but I couldn't verify the Forbes article and system report clearly states that it is using the 3.1 Bus, so I don't think that's the issue here. I would still try all the different ports though.

Comment: @X_841 The Forbes article is not saying the MacBook Pro ports have different functions.  They both function identically.  When the author says "one is for power" he means that when charging a MBP one port will be occupied by a charger, not that only one of the two ports can possibly be used for charging, either can be used to charge the MBP.  Both MBP USB-C ports are capable of charging the laptop, both provide full USB 3.1 and Thunderbolt bandwidth, and both are capable of driving a display.  Ignore that Forbes article because it is just full of ignorance and misinformation.

Comment: Yes, I used fast.com, but also in the Network section, I only get to see "USB 10/100 LAN", not "USB 10/100/1000 LAN", which is what I saw with a previous dongle which did work in the same laptop and same network. Other people have reported using this same dongle up to 1000mbps in other laptops, according to the vendor. I uploaded a photo of it, which also states 1000mbps in the box. I get higher than 100mbps over the same network wirelessly, and used to get around 900mbps when connected with the previous dongle via ethernet cable.

Comment: @MacGuffin yes I am sorry for the confusion. I misinterpreted the article.

Comment: @X_841 the confusion is in the mind of the author of the Forbes article.  The reason for only two ports is because a "pro" is not going to use one port for power, another for a display, and then wonder where to plug in the mouse.  The "PRO" is going to plug in a BlackMagic eGPU that provides power, three video outputs, and four USB 3.1 type A ports.  Then use the second port for his RAID array and 10 Gbps Ethernet.  Myself I'll use about half the time with my MBP I have power on one port and mouse on the other.  The other half has two docks with all kinds of things plugged in.  He's an idiot.

Comment: @Norbert It is the vendors word *it works* against what we can see on the screenshot. System report isn't lying, the established connection is limited by USB 2. It may be a compatability issue with macOS/Macs but tbh I doubt that. I don't really know what else to try other than restart your Mac, SMC reset and NVRAM/PRAM reset, single user mode, but that should not be the problem. Do you have a different dongle you could try? Or maybe you can return that one and get a new one?

Comment: I did try a different dongle, a different model, and it works normally. This dongle is made for 1000mbps but it's only recognised as USB 2 by OSX Catalina. The aim is to make OSX Catalina recognise the dongle properly.

Comment: @Norbert I don't know what else to do other than a clean install of macOS. All the testing you have done points to a MBP hardware or software issue. If you clean install macOS we should be able to rule out software issues. After that, if the USB-C/TB3 ports with other devices work, then I would suspect the dongle again. But  a clean install should be thoughtfully prepared (Backup,...)  and is a harsh measure to get a dongle working. My gut tells me it is not the Mac, but logic currently tells us it must be. Very weird. Have you thought about returning this adaptor and getting a different one?

Comment: The dongle may well be failing in some way. Thanks for your help.